# php stdClass to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem to convert an object stdClass to array.
I have tried in this way:

```
return (array) $booking;
```

or

```
return (array) json_decode($booking,true);
```

or

```
return (array) json_decode($booking);
```

The array before the cast is full with one record, after my try to cast it is empty.
How to cast / convert it without delete its rows?

array before cast:

```
array(1) {   [0]=>   object(stdClass)#23 (36) {     ["id"]=>     string(1) "2"     ["name"]=>     string(0) ""     ["code"]=>     string(5) "56/13"   } }
```

after cast is empty NULL if I try to make a `var_dump($booking);`

I have also tried this function but always empty:

```
public function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
            // Gets the properties of the given object
            // with get_object_vars function
            $d = get_object_vars($d);
        }

        if (is_array($d)) {
            /*
            * Return array converted to object
            * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
            * for recursive call
            */
            return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
        }
        else {
            // Return array
            return $d;
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/var_dump ... http://php.net/var_export - before `return`. And running [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) on an array seems pretty desperate to me, probably sitting too long in front of the computer and it's now time to take a break?

Comment: Just to clarify: `var_dump($booking);` outputs `NULL`?

Comment: after cast yes, and if i try to print this: $booking[0]['id'] return me that not exist

Comment: You might be interested to read: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456) - Anyway, I was asking to `var_dump()` *before* casting. Do not re-use the same variable name btw. if `$booking` was something before casting, it should still be that something *before* casting and not something different afterwards. Differ between input and processing variables otherwise you run into problems that you don't understand any longer what you do there.

Comment: Shortening the question (like removing the custom function code) could be useful to see the accepted answer without having to scroll down

Comment: In the general case, I think this is not possible. Consider if your objects have cycles, dereferencing this into arrays, will end up in an infinite loop... Just wanted to point this issue. For other scenarios, other answers are certainly valid...

Answer (score 563, accepted):

### The *lazy* one-liner method

You can do this in a one liner using the JSON methods if you're willing to lose a tiny bit of performance (though some have reported it being faster than iterating through the objects recursively - most likely because PHP is [slow at calling functions](https://3v4l.org/HmmIB)). "*But I already did this*" you say. Not exactly - you used [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) on the array, but you need to encode it with [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) first.

#### Requirements

The [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) methods. These are automatically bundled in PHP 5.2.0 and up. If you use any older version there's also a [PECL library](http://pecl.php.net/package/json) (that said, in that case you should *really* update your PHP installation. Support for 5.1 stopped in 2006.)

---

### Converting an `array`/`stdClass` -> `stdClass`

```
$stdClass = json_decode(json_encode($booking));
```

---

### Converting an `array`/`stdClass` -> `array`

The manual specifies the second argument of [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) as:

> **assoc**
>   *When `TRUE`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.*

Hence the following line will convert your entire object into an array:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($booking), true);
```

Comment: If `(array) $booking;` in  a `var_dump` is `NULL` (as written by OP), guess what this code will return?

Comment: @hakre It doesn't seem like it's `NULL` after casting it as an array. I think OP means that it's `NULL` after using `json_decode($array)` which makes sense per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). *NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded*

Comment: In the question there are outlined three ways. OP as given the `NULL` information for all three ways.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri The reason it didn't work before was before you were using `json_decode()` on an array. `json_decode` should be used on a JSON string. Therefore, if we encode it as a JSON string first (`json_encode`) and **then** decode it (using our JSON string), then it works fine.

Comment: I have accpeted the other question because I think is better, but your solution is fine thanks a lot

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri No problem - it might (*read: should*) be quicker any way, and this is, as said, just the lazy solution.

Comment: Thanks for explain why is better and I have make a benchmark and it's very fast than the other methods. Thanks @h2ooooooo

Comment: Has everyone forgot that you will lose your types that are not defined in JSON spec (dates for example)? You'll need to have a reviver then if you use this approach. This is only good if you have basic types such as numbers, strings and booleans.

Comment: Great answer, I've been just using json_decode($stdClass, true) ;)

Comment: this answer was very useful in explaining some stuff I didn't know but the encode before is not always necessary, in fact sometimes it converts the data into a string. Recently, the solution for me was just json_decode($stdClass, true);

Comment: The line that work for me was json_decode(json_encode($booking), true);

Answer (score 115):

use this function to get a standard array back of the type you are after...

```
return get_object_vars($booking);
```

Comment: This is better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576902/836697 because it can handle unicode strings.

Comment: However, it is not recursive

Answer (score 60):

Use the built in type cast functionality, simply type

```
$realArray = (array)$stdClass;
```

Comment: I prefer this over json_decode/encode, much cleaner +1

Comment: This method is cleaner, however, it's also not recursive, and works the same as the get_object_vars().

While the json_decode/encode method has the feel of a hack, it works recursively.

Comment: If you have multiple depth objects only the first elements get type cast to an array. n+ deep elements will be still objects. So using json_encode/decode fixes that.

Answer (score 20):

Since it's an array before you cast it, casting it makes no sense.

You may want a recursive cast, which would look something like this:

```
function arrayCastRecursive($array)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $array[$key] = arrayCastRecursive($value);
            }
            if ($value instanceof stdClass) {
                $array[$key] = arrayCastRecursive((array)$value);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($array instanceof stdClass) {
        return arrayCastRecursive((array)$array);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->aaa = 'asdf';
$obj->bbb = 'adsf43';
$arr = array('asdf', array($obj, 3));

var_dump($arr);
$arr = arrayCastRecursive($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

**Result before:**

```
array
    0 => string 'asdf' (length = 4)
  1 => 
    array
        0 =>
        object(stdClass)[1]
          public 'aaa' => string 'asdf' (length = 4)
          public 'bbb' => string 'adsf43' (length = 6)
      1 => int 3
```

**Result after:**

```
array
    0 => string 'asdf' (length = 4)
  1 => 
    array
        0 =>
        array
          'aaa' => string 'asdf' (length = 4)
          'bbb' => string 'adsf43' (length = 6)
      1 => int 3
```

**Note:**

Tested and working with complex arrays where a stdClass object can contain other stdClass objects.

Comment: Great. Now works for stdClass objects that contain stdClass objects :)

Answer (score 18):

This function worked for me:

```
function cvf_convert_object_to_array($data) {

    if (is_object($data)) {
        $data = get_object_vars($data);
    }

    if (is_array($data)) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $data);
    }
    else {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://carlofontanos.com/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php/

Answer (score 16):

Please use following php function to convert php stdClass to array

```
get_object_vars($data)
```

Comment: Note that this function is not recursive.  Refer to the answer by **Carlo Fontanos** for a recursive solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just googled it, and found **[here](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Convert_Object_To_Array-v9p)** a handy function that is useful for converting stdClass object to array recursively.

```
<?php
function object_to_array($object) {
 if (is_object($object)) {
  return array_map(__FUNCTION__, get_object_vars($object));
 } else if (is_array($object)) {
  return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $object);
 } else {
  return $object;
 }
}
?>
```

**EDIT**: I updated this answer with content from linked source (which is also changed now), thanks to mason81 for suggesting me.

Comment: Next time please include the relevant content from the linked source. The link you provided has changed and is now irrelevant and useless.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I use it in Laravel without Eloquent.

```
function getUsers(){ 

   $users = DB::select('select * from users');       
   $data = json_decode(json_encode($users), true); // to array 

   return view('page')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of Carlo's answer that can be used in a class:

```
class Formatter
{
    public function objectToArray($data)
    {
        if (is_object($data)) {
            $data = get_object_vars($data);
        }

        if (is_array($data)) {
            return array_map(array($this, 'objectToArray'), $data);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will read all emails & print the Subject, Body & Date.

```
<?php
  $imap=imap_open("Mailbox","Email Address","Password");
  if($imap){$fixMessages=1+imap_num_msg($imap);  //Check no.of.msgs
/*
By adding 1 to "imap_num_msg($imap)" & starting at $count=1
   the "Start" & "End" non-messages are ignored
*/
    for ($count=1; $count<$fixMessages; $count++){
      $objectOverview=imap_fetch_overview($imap,$count,0);
print '<br>$objectOverview: '; print_r($objectOverview);
print '<br>objectSubject ='.($objectOverview[0]->subject));
print '<br>objectDate ='.($objectOverview[0]->date);
      $bodyMessage=imap_fetchbody($imap,$count,1);
print '<br>bodyMessage ='.$bodyMessage.'<br><br>';
    }  //for ($count=1; $count<$fixMessages; $count++)
  }  //if($imap)
  imap_close($imap);
?>
```

This outputs the following:

```
$objectOverview: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [subject] => Hello
[from] => Email Address [to] => Email Address [date] => Sun, 16 Jul 2017 20:23:18 +0100
[message_id] =>  [size] => 741 [uid] => 2 [msgno] => 2 [recent] => 0 [flagged] => 0 
[answered] => 0 [deleted] => 0 [seen] => 1 [draft] => 0 [udate] => 1500232998 ) )
objectSubject =Hello
objectDate =Sun, 16 Jul 2017 20:23:18 +0100
bodyMessage =Test
```

Having struggled with various suggestions I have used trial & error to come up with this solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best Object to Array function I have - works recursively:

```
function object_to_array($obj, &$arr){
    
    if(!is_object($obj) && !is_array($obj)){
        $arr = $obj;
        return $arr;
    }
    
    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            $arr[$key] = array();
            object_to_array_v2($value, $arr[$key]);
        } else {
            $arr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}

$clean_array = object_to_array($object_data_here);
```