# How to combine two associative arrays in to one?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays as given below:

```
   [0] => array(5) {
    ["part_id"] => string(2) "19"
    ["maker_id"] => string(2) "29"
    ["sale_deduction_type"] => string(1) "1"
    ["sale_deduction_value"] => string(2) "10"
    ["sale_name"] => string(8) "New Year"
  }
```

and new one:

```
[0] => (6) {
        ["bill_id"] => string(2) "31"
        ["part_number"] => string(18) "SN14CNANG56-M-BLUE"
        ["part_id"] => string(2) "19"
        ["part_quantity"] => string(1) "1"
        ["part_rate"] => string(6) "232.00"
        ["part_desc"] => string(12) "this is test"
      }
```

how do i combine these two array1[0] and array2[0] to single array like

```
array[0] => (10) {
        ["bill_id"] => string(2) "31"
        ["part_number"] => string(18) "SN14CNANG56-M-BLUE"
        ["part_id"] => string(2) "19"
        ["part_quantity"] => string(1) "1"
        ["part_rate"] => string(6) "232.00"
        ["part_desc"] => string(12) "this is test"
        ["maker_id"] => string(2) "29"
        ["sale_deduction_type"] => string(1) "1"
        ["sale_deduction_value"] => string(2) "10"
        ["sale_name"] => string(8) "New Year"
  }
```

using array_merge or array_combine was not helpful.

Comment: can you post the php format of the array? That makes it easy for everybody to help. e.g. `array(array('part_id'=>19,'maker_id'=>29))`

Comment: If this data came from JSON, please consider passing `true` as second parameter to `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert object to array and try,

```
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $array1[0], (array) $array2[0]);
```

And as @jack commented above,

If this data came from JSON, please consider passing `true` as second parameter to `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge 2 objects of type stdClass instead of arrays. If the intended output should be an array.
[Convert them to arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array). Then use array_merge.