# Please Help about array in Facebook

Tags: php, arrays

hello I need help to "echo" this array

```
Array ( [location] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 109064359132595 [name] => Malang, Jawa Timur, Indonesia ) [id] => 926370114003325 )
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array

Comment: im new in php, can you show to me

Comment: Read the answer, provided in the question... :)

Comment: not work and i dont understand :(

Comment: now work with foreach function thxs :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help who have same problems, i solved this problems

```
foreach ($data as $tes) { 
echo $tes->name."</ br>\n";}
```

:D