# How to create multiple array with php for standard merging

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I wish to merge to a default one, but I don't know how to create a standard one, here is what is sent from database

```
Array
(
    [WInicio] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idweb_inicio] => 10
                    [logo] => 
                    [portada] => 
                    [descripcion] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    [PROSPECTO_ID] => 143
                    [email] => rrios@droquiven.com.ve
                    [nosotros] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    [template] => 1
                )

        )

    [WServicios] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idweb_servicios] => 31
                    [PROSPECTO_ID] => 143
                    [servicio] => Servicio 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idweb_servicios] => 32
                    [PROSPECTO_ID] => 143
                    [servicio] => Servicio 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idweb_servicios] => 33
                    [PROSPECTO_ID] => 143
                    [servicio] => Servicio 3
                )

        )

    [template] => 1
)
```

I tried to make it but it gives me a lot of errors, because the inners arrays

I hope you can help me.

Comment: show the output you want

Comment: The same as the one on the question

Comment: That is input array but what you want achieve?

Comment: I will want this -> array_default with empty values ("") and the one database is sent (I am using codeigniter), And later merge array_default with array database

Comment: array_merge($array_default, $this_array)  why not?

Comment: Sure but the issues I have now is creating the array structure similar at the output of my question

Comment: Than, what the input array if this output?

Comment: @splash58 is sent from database with codeigniter so I have no clue of the input strucuture

Comment: @splash58 could you check My answer?

Comment: i still don't understand what you do. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got some progress, researched a lot, including the answer of this question here [php stdClass to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array?answertab=votes#tab-top) and made this as my first try:

```
$panel_web_default = array();
        $WInicio = array(
            "idweb_inicio" => 10,
            "logo" => "",
            "portada" => "",
            "descripcion" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
            "PROSPECTO_ID" => $ID,
            "email" => $XEMAIL,
            "nosotros" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
            "template" => "1"
        );
        $panel_web_default["WInicio"]["0"] = json_decode(json_encode($WInicio));;
        $WServicios = array(
            "idweb_servicios" => "31",
            "PROSPECTO_ID" => "143",
            "servicio" => "Servicio 1"
        );
        $panel_web_default["WServicios"]["0"] = json_decode(json_encode($WServicios));
        $WServicios = array(
            "idweb_servicios" => "32",
            "PROSPECTO_ID" => "143",
            "servicio" => "Servicio 2"
        );
        $panel_web_default["WServicios"]["1"] = json_decode(json_encode($WServicios));
        $WServicios = array(
            "idweb_servicios" => "32",
            "PROSPECTO_ID" => "143",
            "servicio" => "Servicio 2"
        );
        $panel_web_default["WServicios"]["2"] = json_decode(json_encode($WServicios));


        array_merge($panel_web_default, $panel_web);
```

Comment: Hey Ricardo, awesome answer. Will help me with a couple of things I was working on.