# convert array to html

Tags: php, html, arrays, arraylist

I get data array make me confuse like this:

```
{  
   "error":0,
   "productcount":"1",
   "page":1,
   "totalpage":1,
   "result":[sorry hidden cust request]
}
```

I want to convert it to html table, how ? please help me...

Comment: Thanks Mr @Jordan S

Comment: Please be more precise concerning what you want to display and how. From your tags we can assume you are using php. So far so good: now you want to display the "stok" param or your whole "result" array, which would result in a table in a table ;)

Comment: Like this : https://storage.googleapis.com/openscreenshot/-/e/3/SkWSWj3e-.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over your result like so, note that the data you show is a JSON object, which you need to convert to an array first:

```
<?php

// this has to be in JSON format
$dataArray = json_decode($yourJSON);

$dataArray = $dataArray["result"][0]["stok"];
?>
<table>
  <tr>

    <td><strong>Ukuran</strong></td>
    <?php foreach($dataArray as $item){?>
      <td> <?= $item["ukuran"] ?> </td>
    <?php } ?>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>Stok</strong></td>
    <?php foreach(dataArray  as $item){?>
      <td> <?= $item["stok"] ?> </td>
    <?php } ?>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr @ju_ for helping me, i got this error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" what this mean ?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array so you first convert your std class into an array

Comment: Ok, thanks Mr ju, i have tried, good but have another error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), i try used is_array() but return null

Comment: try to var_dump($your_data);

Comment: return NULL, sorry if i to much ask

Comment: before that i used $dataArray = json_decode(json_encode($myJson),true); is this true ?

Comment: no, as your data is not a JSON but a apparently a dump of an stdclass its not correct. just follow the instructions in the link i commented earlier

Comment: To assist you further, please post a working phpFiddle of your code.

Comment: for your code just remove the json_encode() and change $dataArray = $dataArray["result"]["stok"] to $dataArray = $dataArray["result"][0]["stok"];

Comment: Thank you very much Mr ju, its work fine... maybe i have learn from you a master PHP :D

Comment: My pleasure. Keep going ;)