# convert data fetched from DB to array in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I fetched data from table 'auction'

```
$players = DB::table('auction')->where('id',$id)->get();
```

I'm getting the data in this form

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Yogesh Singh",
    "year": "BE",
    "branch": "CE",
    "division": "D",
    "achievements": "College Cricket Team",
    "base_price": 5000000,
    "status": 1,
    "manager": 0
  }
]
```

now I need to shift this data into another table 'team', and hence I did

```
DB::table('team')->insert(['player_id' => $id, 'player_type' => $player->player_type, 'name' => $player->name, 'price' => $player->price]);
```

it throws an error saying, Property [player_type] does not exist on this collection instance.

I'm pretty sure i'm not able to convert the data fetched from DB to array.

How do I do this?

Comment: use `DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` before query builder

Comment: this is the error now, Class &#039;App\Http\Controllers\PDO&#039; not found

Comment: Did you have player_type column in your auction table? You are trying to fetch an unknown property

Comment: add `use PDO` namespace in controller@YogeshKumarSingh

Answer (score 2):

Laravel query builder select method returns a variable of Collection type. each member is of type stdclass.

Collection has a toArraye member:

[toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-toarray)

Just notice this function returns back 2 dimension array.

Another way is using collection->first to get first member of collection and convert this stdclass into array using this approach:[php stdClass to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `$players` is returning a `collection` since you used `get()`. Change it to `first()` which will return `Model` instance if exists. Also variable name is `$player` , not `$players`

```
$player = DB::table('auction')->where('id',$id)->first();
```

Now access data like:

```
DB::table('team')->insert(['player_id' => $id, 'player_type' => $player->player_type, 'name' => $player->name, 'price' => $player->price]);
```

**OR**

You can keep the `get()` and access data like this:

```
DB::table('team')->insert(['player_id' => $id, 'player_type' => $player[0]->player_type, 'name' => $player[0]->name, 'price' => $player[0]->price]);
```

Hope it's helpful.