# creating multidimensional array of data doesn't produce array on javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Good Day,

im just confused as to why my data structure doesnt render array, its displays list of objects instead, the code below aims to store days of months on array structure,

```
$calendar = [];
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $s=date ("w", mktime (0,0,0,$month,1,$year));

    for ($ds=1;$ds<=$s;$ds++) {

     $row_day = new stdClass();
     $row_day->day = $d;
     $row_day->is_holiday = $is_holiday;
     $row_day->is_paydate = $is_paydate;
     //day of the week
     $row_day->dotw = date("w",mktime (0,0,0,$month,$d,$year));
     $row_day->is_funds_due = $is_funds_due;

    $calendar[$m][] = $row_day;

    }

}

echo json_encode(array('type'=>2,'data'=>$calendar));
```

but when I console.log on my js it produces this structure.. which clearly is not an array..  [image]

am I wrong on building my structure?

its just that its easier to manipulate if its on array mode. since you can just use data.length, but in my case it doesnt work..

thanks for reading, Have a good Day!

Comment: ahh just for type identification on response so I could format accordingly

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but can't you just use `json_encode($calendar)`? You seem to be calling `array()` with arguments that would create an object rather than an array.

Comment: I actually need to add parameters on my returned value  for additional conditions.. I really think that what I need is possible its just that I have no idea yet on how to achieve this.. thanks for passing by anyways..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **array** Instead of **std class** (it's an object)

```
$calendar = [];
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $s=date ("w", mktime (0,0,0,$month,1,$year));

    for ($ds=1;$ds<=$s;$ds++) {
        $row_day = array();
        $row_day['day'] = $d;
        $row_day['is_holiday'] = $is_holiday;
        $row_day['is_paydate'] = $is_paydate;
        //day of the week
        $row_day['dotw'] = date("w",mktime (0,0,0,$month,$d,$year));
        $row_day['is_funds_due'] = $is_funds_due;

        $calendar[$m] = $row_day;
    }
}

echo json_encode(array('type'=>2,'data'=>$calendar));
```

Answer (score 1):

`stdClass()` is [an object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), not an array.

There is an easy (lazy?) way to take your object and turn it into an array found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array)

The other option would be to instantiate your data as an array in the first place.

```
$row_day['day'] = $d;
$row_day['is_holiday'] = $is_holiday;
$row_day['is_paydate'] = $is_paydate;
```