# "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" in laravel API resource collection error when using db::paginate()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, resources, laravel-6

When I am using laravel Collection & DB query pagination. getting the following error.

```
new UserCollection(DB::table('users')->paginate());
```

[image: e]

I am using elequent pagination as follows,

```
new UserCollection(User::paginate());
```

It works fine as follows.

[image: en]

I have upgraded from Laravel 5.8 to 6.

Comment: The user paginated is already a collection itself. why are you creating a collection over your pagination? . if you returns an ajax then the collection get lost and only will return an object

Comment: This is API resource response to format API response.

Comment: You need to convert stdClass to array. Here is your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array).

Comment: this is general solution but how can I apply this here. `API resource`

Answer (score 0):

**Try is one**

```
 User::paginate();
You need to convert stdClass to array
```