# Convert stdClass array to simple array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `php 7.1` and have the following array:

[image]

However, I would simply like to have the following array:

`array(3808, 3807, 3806, 3805)`

Any suggestions how to convert it to array?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: please provide the code you try to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php stdClass to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array)

Comment: array_column($lastPostIDs, 'ID')

Answer (score 1):

`array_column()` function will help:

```
$ids = array_column($records, 'ID');
print_r($ids);
```

Will output just array of ID's.

Check docs for it [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Thx! Any suggestion how to disassociate the array. I still get `0 => 3385` etc.

Comment: array_values() will return just array of values. Check it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php .  But 0=>3385 is ok because it is array and it should have indexes

Comment: @Anna.Klee That's how an array is shown. It just says at 0th index you have 3385.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the Object to an Array and use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to return an array of values from a specific key.

```php
$a = (object) [
    0 => [ 'ID' => 3808],
    1 => [ 'ID' => 3807],
    2 => [ 'ID' => 3806],
    3 => [ 'ID' => 3805],
];

$b = array_column((array)$a, 'ID');
// $b = [3808,3807,3806,3805]
```

*Note:* `(array)$a` enforces Array conversion. Conversely, `(object)$a` will convert an Array to a stdClass Object.

Comment: Apparently, the `(array)$a` seems redundant in PHP's context.

Comment: @vivek_23 If the first parameter in `array_column` is an Object you will get the error, 'array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in...'. You must convert an Object to an Array to use `array_column`.

Comment: I do know that. I said from OP's point of view and since he has an array of objects, the conversion again to an array is not needed. I meant more in terms of array_column() functioning since it usually deals with array of arrays instead of array of objects and correctly understands that `ID` is a property of an object that exists and not some key in an array.

Comment: Bingo. It does check that via a switch case as [shown here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L4222).

Comment: @vivek_23 I get you now. My mistake -- I misread the image as the other way around -- Object of Arrays, not Array of Objects as stated in the question.