# How to return data as JSON in moodle webservices

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am creating a webservice in moodle and want to return my std object as a JSON,

```
public static function add_attendance_lti($attendanceObject)
    {
......
$lti_updated = [
            'id' => $insert_new_attendance,
            'code' => $statusCode,
            'message' => $message,
            'data' => json_encode($AttendanceLog)
        ];
        return $lti_updated;
  }

public static function add_attendance_lti_returns()
    {
        return new external_single_structure(
            array(
                'id' => new external_value(PARAM_RAW, 'New Attendance id'),
                'code' => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'status code of response'),
                'message' => new external_value(PARAM_TEXT, 'message returned'),
                'data' => new external_value(PARAM_RAW, 'Return Value')
            )
        );
    }
```

Here i am converting the $AttendanceLog std object to JSON using json_encode(), but this returns the following data,

```
{
    "id": null,
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Attendance Record already exists",
    "data": "{\"sessionid\":\"18\",\"timetaken\":1643335205,\"studentid\":\"4\",\"takenby\":\"3\",\"statusset\":\"49,51,52,50\",\"statusid\":\"52\"}"
}
```

How can i return a normal "data" JSON object without the \"

Comment: Are you `json_encode()`’ing `$lti_leave` as well? Why would you need to do this twice…?

Comment: $AttendanceLog is a std object so i am converting it to JSON using json_encode(), i don't understand what you mean by json_encode()’ing $lti_leave.

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding to json your string in *add_attendance_lti* with json_encode, and the resulting string will be escaped in *add_attendance_lti_returns*. Hence this slashed encoding.

You can try to convert your *std object* to an *array* in *add_attendance_lti* :

```
public static function add_attendance_lti($attendanceObject)
    {
......
$lti_updated = [
            'id' => $insert_new_attendance,
            'code' => $statusCode,
            'message' => $message,
            'data' => json_decode(json_encode($AttendanceLog), true)
        ];
        return $lti_updated;
  }
```

(see [php stdClass to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576762/php-stdclass-to-array))

That way, this method will return an array, and the value of the json for the key "*data*" at the other end will be a json - not an escaped string.

Comment: i get this error using your solution, { "exception": "invalid_response_exception", "errorcode": "invalidresponse", "message": "Invalid response value detected" }

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$AttendanceLog` variable without using `json_encode` in data key and after that convert $`lti_updated` with `json_encode` like this

```
json_encode($lti_updated);
```

in return like

```
return json_encode($lti_updated);
```

Comment: i get this error using your solution, {
    "exception": "invalid_response_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidresponse",
    "message": "Invalid response value detected"
}